# Visualize $A_4$ and $\langle x, z\rangle$ isomorphic to the Klein 4 group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, visualization

[image]

Page 136 says 
Following Step 1 of Definition 7.5, the top of Figure 7.23 shows $A_4$ organized by the
subgroup $\langle x, z\rangle$ (which is isomorphic to the Klein $4$ group. This reorganization required using arrows for the generators $x$ and $z$, as well as a generator that connects cosets of $\langle x, z\rangle$, in this case $a$. Step 2 of Definition 7.5 asks us to collapse each of the three left cosets of $\langle x, z\rangle$ into a single node, uniting any arrows that are thereby rendered redundant.

This is from Nathan Carter page 136 figure 7.23 Visual Group Theory.

Question 1. I don't understand how these  Cayley diagrams represent $A_4$. What do the blue, green, red mean?
Question 2. Where's subgroup $H = \langle x, z\rangle$ that's isomorphic to the Klein $4$ group? What color(s)?

**EDIT @Richard Peterson 2/2/2014** ----

Question 3. How do you see $A_4 = ($ any of the 3 cycles under $ )V_4$ without actually calculating all the permutations in orange underneath?

I know $A_4$ is 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand either issue. For Question 1, according to your diagram, blue, green, and red respectively denote multiplication by $a$, $z$, and $x$. For Question 2, the upper coset is $H$...?

Comment: Note that the _nodes_ of a Cayley graph represent _elements_ of a group, while _edges_ represent (left multiplication) _mappings_. Your intent to identify subgroups (sets of nodes) with colors (sets of edges) therefore seems anomalous. (Of course, each group element corresponds to a left multiplication mapping, but it doesn't seem a good idea to "mix" nodes and edges this way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take x and z to be any two of the three nonidentity permutations in V4 of the subgroup lattice you provided at the bottom of your message. V4, (as you know) is the Klein 4 group. It is the top square in each of Nathan Carter's diagrams, with e being the identity and y equal to xz, y being whichever nonidentity permutation in V4 that you DIDN'T choose when you chose x and z.

Take "a" to be ANY three-cycle element in the group A4. As user86418 said, the nodes are group elements and the colored arrows represent (left) multiplication by the group elements x (in green), z (in red), and $"a"$ (in blue).

So, for example, the blue arrow from node y pointing to node d means ay=d. Each of the three squares in the diagram are cosets of V4. V4 is called H. The top square is V4=H=eH as stated above, the right lower square is aV4=aH, and the left lower square is aaH....I may have overexplained parts of this, but some other person besides you may find the extra explanation helpful... (Note the reason I put "a" in quotes was to try to be unconfusing, hopefully I wasn't more confusing--I did it to mark $"a"$ as ANY group element in $A_4$ when it wasn't the one letter English word   *a*, except when I multiplied by the group element "a", like aH.)

Comment: thanks. i upvoted for you. can you please reply to my edit that i made in my question --- in your answer?

Comment: I'll try to help, is your new question to do with the permutations you boxed in yellow? The klein 4 group is the identity along with the three double traanspositions you boxed in yellow.

Comment: Query3:How to see A4=(any of the 3 cycles)*V w/out calc'ing all the permutations?-Take the 3cycle (123) and compose it w/the identy coset id*V=V(compose on either left or right, they'll be the same, since V normal), u'll get: coset (123)*V={(123),(134),(243),(142)}.Now, if u compose (123)*V w/ (123) AGAIN, u'll get (123)*(123)*V=(132)*V={(132),(234),(124),(143)}.Use this as template for what all 3cycles will do, bcuz they will give u the xact same 3 cosets, bcuz V is normal-But was that actully what your query was? I might be saying stuff u already know, so please reply to this.